# How do I store the printed result of a generator in a variable for further use?

Tags: python, generator

I used a generator to create a 10 by 10 of 'O's:

```
board = []

for x in range(0, 10):

    board.append(["O"] * 10)

def board_generator(layout):

    for y in layout:

        yield (" ".join(y))

my_board = board_generator(board)
```

Then I set imputed the result into a variable, but when I tried outputting it to another source, I got this:

```
<generator object board_generator at 0x0135AAF0>
```

I tried to get the printed result I wanted by doing this:

```
def print_board(boards):

    for i in boards:

        print(i)
```

However, I could not place impute this into a variable because it does not return anything, therefore I could not output it to a text file. How do I fix this?

Comment: `print(list(my_board))` creates a list of the generated values

Answer (score 1):

Try `my_board = list(board_generator(board))`.

A generator is different to a regular function in that it requires you to either iterate its contents (for example, via `next`) or exhaust it via another function (for example, `list` or `set`).

See [What does the “yield” keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but I just realized an easier way of accomplishing what I am trying to do. (Which is build a battleship file that outputs data into a text file for another python file to read)